# R match between two comma-separated strings

Tags: regex, r, pattern-matching, match

I am trying to find an elegant way to find matches between the two following character columns in a data frame. The complicated part is that either string can contain a comma-separated list, and if a member of one list is a match for any member of the other list, then that whole entry would be considered a match. I'm not sure how well I've explained this, so here's sample data and output:

Alt1:

- AT
- A
- G
- CGTCC,AT
- CGC

Alt2:

- AA
- A
- GG
- AT,GGT
- CG

Expected Match per row:

- Row 1 = none
- Row 2 = A
- Row 3 = none
- Row 4 = AT
- Row 5 = none

Non-working solutions:

First attempt: merge entire data frames by desired columns, then match up the alt columns shown above:

```
match1 = data.frame(merge(vcf.df, ref.df, by=c("chr", "start", "end",  "ref")))
matches = unique(match1[unlist(sapply(match1$Alt1 grep, match1$Alt2, fixed=TRUE)),])
```

Second method, using findoverlaps feature from VariantAnnoatation/Granges:

```
findoverlaps(ranges(vcf1), ranges(vcf2))
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

**Solution**
Thanks to @Marat Talipov's answer below, the following solution works to compare two comma-separated strings:

```
> ##read in edited kaviar vcf and human ref
> ref <-     readVcfAsVRanges("ref.vcf.gz", humie_ref)
Warning message:
In .vcf_usertag(map, tag, ...) :
  ScanVcfParam ‘geno’ fields not present: ‘AD’

> ##rename chromosomes to match with vcf files
> ref <- renameSeqlevels(ref, c("1"="chr1"))

> ##################################
> ## Gather VCF files to process  ## 
> ##################################
> ##data frame *.vcf.gz files in directory path
> vcf_path <- data.frame(path=list.files(vcf_dir, pattern="*.vcf.gz$",  full=TRUE))

> ##read in everything but sample data for speediness
> vcf_param = ScanVcfParam(samples=NA)
> vcf <- readVcfAsVRanges("test.vcf.gz", humie_ref, param=vcf_param)

> #################
> ## Match SNP's ##
> #################
> ##create data frames of info to match on
> vcf.df = data.frame(chr =as.character(seqnames(vcf)), start = start(vcf),     end = end(vcf), ref = as.character(ref(vcf)), 
+                     alt=alt(vcf), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> ref.df = data.frame(chr =as.character(seqnames(ref)), start =     start(ref), end = end(ref), 
+                     ref = as.character(ref(ref)), alt=alt(ref),     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> 
> ##merge based on all positional fields except vcf
> col_match = data.frame(merge(vcf.df, ref.df, by=c("chr", "start", "end", "ref")))

> library(stringi)
> ##split each alt column by comma and bind together
> M1 <- stri_list2matrix(sapply(col_match$alt.x,strsplit,','))
> M2 <- stri_list2matrix(sapply(col_match$alt.y,strsplit,','))
> M <- rbind(M1,M2)

> ##compare results
> result <- apply(M,2,function(z) unique(na.omit(z[duplicated(z)])))

> ##add results column to col_match df for checking/subsetting
> col_match$match = result
> head(col_match)
   chr    start      end ref alt.x alt.y match
1 chr1 39998059 39998059   A     G     G     G
2 chr1 39998059 39998059   A     G     G     G
3 chr1 39998084 39998084   C     A     A     A
4 chr1 39998084 39998084   C     A     A     A
5 chr1 39998085 39998085   G     A     A     A
6 chr1 39998085 39998085   G     A     A     A
```

Comment: Are Alt1 and Alt2 of equal length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case that input lists are of equal length and you'd like to compare list elements in the pairwise manner, you could use this solution:

```
library(stringi)

M1 <- stri_list2matrix(sapply(Alt1,strsplit,','))
M2 <- stri_list2matrix(sapply(Alt2,strsplit,','))
M <- rbind(M1,M2)

result <- apply(M,2,function(z) unique(na.omit(z[duplicated(z)])))
```

Sample input:

```
Alt1 <- list('AT','A','G','CGTCC,AT','CGC','GG,CC')
Alt2 <- list('AA','A','GG','AT,GGT','CG','GG,CC')
```

Output:

```
# [[1]]
# character(0)
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "A"
# 
# [[3]]
# character(0)
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "AT"
# 
# [[5]]
# character(0)
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] "GG" "CC"
```

Comment: Since you are using "stringi", why aren't you using `stri_split`, which let's you simplify to a matrix directly?

Comment: how about `mapply(match,Alt1,Alt2)` ?

Comment: @AnandaMahto, because `stri_list2matrix` is the only function I know in `stringi` )

Comment: @Metrics, it will return only exact match. The question is about also matching comma-separating substrings

Comment: Sadly, my input lists are of different lengths. Is there a way to modify it to work on differing lengths? It's a great approach... thank you.

Comment: Could you show sample input and output for the case of lists with different lengths?

Comment: Ok, instead of trying to compare both vcf files directly, I first subset them on other positional criteria, and from that data frame of matches (equal lenght) I ran this and it works perfectly. I have been trying to get this all day, thank you so much!! I'll post my code as an update to my question.

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this:

```
Alt1 <- list('AT','A','G',c('CGTCC','AT'),'CGC')
Alt2 <- list('AA','A','GG',c('AT','GGT'),'CG')
# make sure you change the lists within in the lists into vectors

matchlist <- list()
for (i in 1:length(Alt1)){
  matchlist[[i]] <- ifelse(Alt1[[i]] %in% Alt2[[i]], 
                           paste("Row",i,"=",c(Alt1[[i]],Alt2[[i]])[duplicated(c(Alt1[[i]],Alt2[[i]]))],sep=" "),
                           paste("Row",i,"= none",sep=" ")) 
}
print(matchlist)
```

Comment: I think you can replace `(Alt1[[i]] %in% Alt2[[i]]) | (Alt2[[i]] %in% Alt1[[i]])` by `intersect(Alt1[[i]], Alt2[[i]])`

Comment: I think you're right! Thanks. I am not near r right now, I will try later.

Comment: I tried both of the suggestions above and received the following error:

`Error in ifelse((Alt1[[i]] %in% Alt2[[i]]) | (Alt2[[i]] %in% Alt1[[i]]),  : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'yes' in selecting a method for function 'ifelse': Error in c(Alt1[[i]], Alt2[[i]])[[any(duplicated(c(Alt1[[i]], Alt2[[i]])))]] : 
  attempt to select less than one element
> print(matchlist)
list()`

Comment: Are you sure alt1 and alt2 are lists and if so, do they have the same length?

Answer (score 1):

Sticking with the `stringi` package, you could do something like this, using the `Alt1` and `Alt2` data from Marat's answer.

```
library(stringi)

f <- function(x, y) {
    ssf <- stri_split_fixed(c(x, y), ",", simplify = TRUE)
    if(any(sd <- stri_duplicated(ssf))) ssf[sd] else NA_character_
}

Map(f, Alt1, Alt2)
# [[1]]
# [1] NA
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "A"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] NA
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "AT"
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] NA
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] "GG" "CC"
```

Or in base R, we can use `scan()` to separate the strings with commas.

```
g <- function(x, y, sep = ",") {
    s <- scan(text = c(x, y), what = "", sep = sep, quiet = TRUE)
    s[duplicated(s)]
}
Map(g, Alt1, Alt2)
```

Comment: Awesome, I'll give that a shot!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringr)
```

## Sample data frame

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("apple,banana,orange", "grape,pear", "cherry,kiwi"), col2 = c("banana,kiwi", "grape,pear", "orange,apple"))
```

## Function to find matching values

```
find_matches <- function(x, y) {
x_vec <- str_split(x, ",")[[1]]
y_vec <- str_split(y, ",")[[1]]
intersect(x_vec, y_vec)
}
```

## Apply function to columns and store results in new column

```
df$matches <- mapply(find_matches, df$col1, df$col2)
```

## View results

```
df
```